# How to specify the path where CMake is installed in the CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I downloaded the portable CMake version from the official site, and installed it in my home directory（`~/usr`) because I don't have root or sudo permission.

**How do I specify the path where CMake is installed in CMakeLists.txt, such as `~/usr/cmake-path/bin/cmake`?**

**Note**: I don't want to use the default version of CMake on the Linux system for it's too old (version 2.6)

PS:

I know of the variable `CMAKE_COMMAND` which may be useful for my question, but I don't know how to use it!

Comment: Why do you want this path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake will use whatever path the running CMake executable is in. Furthermore, it may get confused if you switch paths between runs without clearing the cache.

So what you have to do is simply instead of running `cmake <path_to_src>` from the command line, run `~/usr/cmake-path/bin/cmake <path_to_src>`.

You may want to add an alias or a shell script to the path that is a little more typeable (so you only have to type `my_cmake <path_to_src>` or something like that).

Note that there is no clean way to solve this by just editing the `CMakeLists.txt`. While in theory you could have CMake 2.6 run an outer CMake script that does nothing but running an inner CMake script from a 3.0 executable, that's just a dirty hack. Just run the correct executable from the command line and you should be fine.

Comment: I have to try this before, howerver, `cmake_need_version` will still check  the default version of system not the custom version although I have set `export alias cmake="~/usr/cmake-path/bin/cmake`,  anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @YoungkingWang Please make sure that you really end up running the correct executable. `cmake_minimum_required` should not be concerned with any other installed versions on the system and only look at the currently running binary.

Answer (score 15):

I feel a more robust solution is to prepend your cmake path to the PATH environment variable.

```
export PATH=~/usr/cmake-path/bin:$PATH
```

If your on an Ubuntu/Debian system you can add this command to your ~/.bashrc to execute it with every terminal session.  Note, this change will only affect *your* account and you can set it without administrator permissions.

This way you only need to type `cmake` and the desired version will be found first.

Comment: This is very reasonable advice if you only ever need to run the newer CMake version. I personally prefer the explicit approach since it is usually easier to see when something goes wrong (like, when the custom executable is moved or deleted for some reason), but I can see that people might prefer this one for convenience.

Comment: @ComicSansMS That makes sense, but at the same time CMake requires that `minimum_cmake_required` be set ([since version 2.6.0](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0000.html)), which if set to the newer version will quickly bring attention to the user.

Answer (score 0):

best advice is to install cmake in a sandbox environment rather than on your own, this is the entire environment is preserved while benefiting in increased flexibility. cmake depends on this for existence otherwise your environment becomes a ‘version hell’.

Answer (score -2):

You set the install directory using the flag `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` during your `CMake` build as follows:

```
cmake path/to/sourcedir \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=path/to/install \
```

Don't forget to precede any `CMAKE_FLAGS` with `-D`.

If you want to include a custom install prefix in your `CMakeLists.txt`, then you can include the following:

```
SET(MY_INSTALL_PREFIX "/path/to/install" CACHE PATH "Prefix added to install directories")
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${MY_INSTALL_PREFIX}" CACHE INTERNAL "Prefix added to install directories" FORCE)
```