# visual studio code [cmake] CMake 3.9 or higher is required. You are running version 3.3.2

Tags: linux, cmake, version

Hi in Visual Studio Code it shows when I want to build my project:

`CMake 3.9 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.3.2`

I dont know how to upgrade the cmake version...

It still shows:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.3.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

```
$ sudo cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

My main problem is that I want to use cmake 3.9 in Visual Studio Code. But as I run it as normal user I guess I have no access to the sudo cmake :((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux

Thank you :D

Comment: As a normal user (i.e. _not_ with `sudo`), run `which cmake` and report the output.

Comment: should I do something like this: export PATH=~/usr/cmake-path/bin:$PATH ?  So VSCode can maybe access to /usr/local/bin/cmake ... but I am not really sure if this makes sense... why should VSCode should access on this path... i think it won't change the VSCode path to Cmake :(

Comment: You could specify exact CMake executable to be used by VSCode via setting option `cmake.cmakePath`: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#cmake-cmakepath.

Comment: ok first thing I can see: // Name/path of the CMake executable to use.
 "cmake.cmakePath": "cmake",

Answer (score 2):

It would've been helpful if you had provided your linux distribution.

If it's a debian based system, running `sudo apt install cmake` should update it. 
If it's Arch based, run `sudo pacman -S cmake`

If its something besides that, you will have to figure out your package manager and install cmake using that.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: I guess the packet manager doesnt support newer versions than what I have... I just want cmake 3.9 or never

Comment: now I tried some guideline to install it manually ................. but of of course (ironic) it doesnt work :D this is what I tried: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/796/install-upgrade-cmake-3.12.1-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-alternatives

Comment: The make install command will replace the existing binary in /usr/local/bin/cmake. This can be verified using:  cmake --version .... ok I tried it:  $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.3.2                                                                                                              they are just joking right?

Comment: I will try: https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-from-the-command-line              NICE it shows the error : - Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at Utilities/cmcurl/CMakeLists.txt:505 (message):

Comment: Also doesnt work :D                             https://askubuntu.com/questions/829310/how-to-upgrade-cmake-in-ubuntu

Comment: what should I do? eat my pc?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS comes with CMake 3.16. You are clearly not using the distro-provided cmake. If you are at the command line, you can determine which CMake is in your `PATH` by running `which cmake`.

Comment: `$which cmake /tools/Xilinx19//SDK/2019.1/tps/lnx64/cmake-3.3.2/bin/cmake`  and as sudo`~$ sudo which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake`                 yes it looks like a really strange path!

Comment: $PATH shows this: `/tools/Xilinx19//SDK/2019.1/tps/lnx64/cmake-3.3.2` should I change it to somewhere else? they say something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986541/how-to-specify-the-path-where-cmake-is-installed-in-the-cmakelists-txt/25991335

Comment: so cmake/ubuntu program/s can be installed in different directories or what

Comment: huh weird, maybe try `apt-get purge cmake` and then building from source again ?

Comment: hi Rachit, before I do this :  I checked in my $PATH that there is a path to cmake but 3.3.2.. when I follow this path I see a folder which I also know from https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/796/install-upgrade-cmake-3.12.1-ubuntu-14.04-trusty-alternatives or better from a utube video I saw. The also install it. And the folder will look like the one that is already in the $PATH. So maybe if I install cmake in tools and den add its path to $PATH then my VSC will choose the right one

Comment: ah I see that I have a "source /tools/..." in my .profile! I hope this is the reason. I dont know what source means. I will google it . But I know I had to write it because Xilinx didnt work without it xD

Answer (score 1):

My colleague had the same issue using a similar version of Xilinx tools. For some reason the cmake version that comes with the crosscompiling environment is used as the default path for cmake.

For the console adding

```
export "PATH=/path/to/cmake/bin/dir:${PATH}"
```

(where `/path/to/cmake/bin/dir` is the directory containing the cmake executable) to the end of `~/.bashrc` worked for "fixing" bash. Note that this may result in different tools being used. For this reason I recommend installing cmake into a custom directory. (My colleague had to install cmake by unpacking a `.tar.gz` file containing the binary files anyways, so the cmake tools ended up in a separate dir anyways.)

The IDE probably doesn't use the bash environment variables, but usually you can speficy the absolute path for the cmake executable instead of using `cmake` by modifying the settings. For Visual Studio Code you can go to Settings and edit `Cmake: Cmake path` in `Extensions > CMake tools configuration` and change it to `/usr/local/bin/cmake`.

Comment: I downlaoded the *.sh file version 3.22 from cmake site.  Pasted it in /usr/local/bin . "installed" it there. did the export like you said. ran "code" from the same shell and then it worked xD

Comment: Now I can compile my program again ... I will be happy for the next hours. But need to come back to look deeper into the `Cmake: Cmake path` like you said!!